# Como calcular la edad, dependiendo del dia en que se calcule

Tags: java

estoy haciendo una aplicación, en donde al introducir la fecha de nacimiento me calcula la edad, pero la clave esta en que si el próximo cumpleaños esta mas cerca del anterior ya celebrado, me aumente un año a la edad. tengo este código pero no consigo que funcione bien, sobre todo si cumplo a principio de año y estamos a final, no me suma un año.

```
private String getAge(int year, int month, int day) {
        Calendar dob = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

        dob.set(year, month, day);
        int diaAsegurado = dob.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
        int diaHoy = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

        int age = today.get(Calendar.YEAR) - dob.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        if (diaHoy < diaAsegurado) {
            if ((diaAsegurado - diaHoy) > (today.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) / 3)) {
                age--;
            }
        }

        Integer ageInt = new Integer(age);
        String ageS = ageInt.toString();

        return ageS;
    }
```

Comment: Podrias explicar la logica de calculo en tu codigo? ya que no entiendo porque le restas uno a la edad...

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar. la verdad es que no te se explicar muy bien, soy novato en esto y conseguí sacarlo mirando muchos foros y me ayudo un amigo también. básicamente lo que necesito es que si su próximo cumpleaños esta a menos de 180 días, aumente un año a la edad. pero me falla al cambio de año.

Comment: Ok. empecemos pora arreglar la pregunta. Miar por favor el [tour] y tambien [ask]. Despues, deja solo la funcion que calcula la edad. Cambia la etiqueta, android es un sistema operativo, no un lenguaje. Supongo que esto es Java no? pone esa etiqueta. Y veamos si podemos solucionar tu problema.

Comment: ok, muchas gracias. voy a arreglarlo

Comment: Que version de Java estas usando?

Comment: estoy usando android studio, con api minima 17

Comment: @jechu85 Por favor no solo copies el código de otras paginas [como de Stack Overflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38967422/calculate-age-from-birthdate) y que aquí te hagamos el trabajo. Lee [Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: hola, este código no es copiado y pegado, es el que uso y como he dicho sacado de googlear y con ayuda de un amigo. pero resulta que tiene un fallo al cambiar de año y pido ayuda ya que no consigo encontrar la solución yo solo. no deseo que nadie realice mi trabajo solo pido ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Este es un método para obtener la edad de acuerdo a el día, mes y año de nacimiento, como comentas debe realizarse una comprobación para determinar si el cumpleaños es posterior a la fecha actual, es decir, si hoy es el mismo mes pero aún no llega el día:

```
public static int calcularEdad(int day, int month, int year) {
    Calendar fechaNacimiento = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
    Calendar fechaActual = Calendar.getInstance();

    //Calcula diferencias.
    int years = fechaActual.get(Calendar.YEAR) - fechaNacimiento.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int months = fechaActual.get(Calendar.MONTH) - fechaNacimiento.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int days = fechaActual.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - fechaNacimiento.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    if(months < 0 //Aun no es mes de cumpleaños.
        || (months == 0 && days < 0)){//Es el mes pero no ha llegado el día.
        years--; //Se resta 1 a la diferencia de años.
    }
    return years;
}
```

Este es un ejemplo de uso:

```
//14 de febrero de 1083
String edad = calcularEdad(14, 2, 1983);
```

para obtener un valor en la variable edad de:

```
35
```

Comment: hola muchas gracias por escribirme, lo acabo de ver, pero resulta que no deseo solo la edad simplemente. si no, que si esta mas próximo a cumplir años, que cuando los cumplió me añada +1 a la edad

Comment: después de estar indagando toda la tarde, creo que no me sale por que tengo mal planteado la forma de realizarlo. Yo estoy intentando hacerlo de una vez, pero, no es así, primero debo calcular la edad que se tiene, eso ya esta echo, y después por otro lado, tengo que calcular los días que restan hasta el próximo cumpleaños y si este ultimo resultado es menos de 180 días, sumar +1 a la edad. ¿que opináis? creo que así tiene mas sentido.

Cuando lo consiga edito el código por si alguien en un futuro le interesa.

Comment: esto no funciona si el mes que cumple esta a 1 mes de la fecha actual

Answer (score 1):

Hola he podido solucionar este tema, paso el código por si a alguien le interesa. te calcula la edad y aumenta un año si estas mas próximo a cumplir años que el que ya has cumplido (yo nací en enero y tengo 33 años, pues el sistema me indica que tengo 34, ya que estoy mas cerca de los 34 que de los 33 ahora en octubre).

seleccionarnacimiento = donde introduzco mi edad de nacimiento (editext)
FechaNacimientoCompleta = variante donde almaceno la fecha completa dd/MM/yyyy
FechaNacimiento = variante donde almaceno la edad calculada

```
            String fechaInicio = seleccionarnacimiento.getText().toString();
            String fechaActual = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date());
            Date date = new Date();
            DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
            String[] aFechaIng = fechaInicio.split("/");
            Integer diaInicio = Integer.parseInt(aFechaIng[0]);
            Integer mesInicio = Integer.parseInt(aFechaIng[1]);
            Integer anioInicio = Integer.parseInt(aFechaIng[2]);

            String[] aFecha = fechaActual.split("/");
            Integer diaActual = Integer.parseInt(aFecha[0]);
            Integer mesActual = Integer.parseInt(aFecha[1]);
            Integer anioActual = Integer.parseInt(aFecha[2]);


            int b = 0;
            int dias = 0;
            int mes = 0;
            int anios = 0;
            int meses = 0;
            mes = mesInicio - 1;
            if (mes == 2) {
                if ((anioActual % 4 == 0) && ((anioActual % 100 != 0) || (anioActual % 400 == 0))) {
                    b = 29;
                } else {
                    b = 28;
                }
            } else if (mes <= 7) {
                if (mes == 0) {
                    b = 31;
                } else if (mes % 2 == 0) {
                    b = 30;
                } else {
                    b = 31;
                }
            } else if (mes > 7) {
                if (mes % 2 == 0) {
                    b = 31;
                } else {
                    b = 30;
                }
            }
            if ((anioInicio > anioActual) || (anioInicio == anioActual && mesInicio > mesActual)
                    || (anioInicio == anioActual && mesInicio == mesActual && diaInicio > diaActual)) {
            } else {
                if (mesInicio <= mesActual) {
                    anios = anioActual - anioInicio;
                    if (diaInicio <= diaActual) {
                        meses = mesActual - mesInicio;
                        dias = b - (diaInicio - diaActual);
                    } else {
                        if (mesActual == mesInicio) {
                            anios = anios - 1;
                        }
                        meses = (mesActual - mesInicio - 1 + 12) % 12;
                        dias = b - (diaInicio - diaActual);
                    }
                } else {
                    anios = anioActual - anioInicio - 1;
                    if (diaInicio > diaActual) {
                        meses = mesActual - mesInicio - 1 + 12;
                        dias = b - (diaInicio - diaActual);
                    } else {
                        meses = mesActual - mesInicio + 12;
                        dias = diaActual - diaInicio;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (meses*30 >= 180){
                asegurado.setFechaNacimientoCompleta(seleccionarnacimiento.getText().toString());
                asegurado.setFechaNacimiento( String.valueOf(anios + 1));

            }else{
                asegurado.setFechaNacimientoCompleta(seleccionarnacimiento.getText().toString());
                asegurado.setFechaNacimiento(String.valueOf(anios));}
```

Informo: el codigo original no es mio, es de: 
https://www.mbajava.com/2015/04/restar-2-fechas-en-java-codigo.html.
Yo solamente lo he modificado y adaptado a mi necesidad

Comment: Está muy bien, pero por favor considera darle un nombre a las variables, que sea significativo, sino tu solución más que útil puede ser confusa

Comment: hola, muchas gracias por tu consejo. lo tendré en cuenta